# ERROR 2002 (HY000) on crouton ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mysql, sockets, ubuntu-12.04

I've reinstalled mySQL several times and this error still seems to be occurring whenever I run `mysql -u root -p':

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
```

I've went through all the solutions that I've found and it seems to not help.

Yes, a /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock file exists.

When I run the command: `sudo service mysqld start`, I get `mysqld: unrecognized service`

There isn't a /etc/my.cnf file but there is a /etc/mysql/my.cnf which is as follows:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log

#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB

#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#`enter code here`
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#

# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

the following is the log when I ran 'sudo apt-get install mysql-server'

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libhtml-template-perl libmysqlclient18 mysql-client-5.5
  mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
Suggested packages:
  libipc-sharedcache-perl tinyca mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libhtml-template-perl libmysqlclient18 mysql-client-5.5
  mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.5
  mysql-server-core-5.5
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/26.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 95.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
(Reading database ... 87126 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql-common (from .../mysql-common_5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmysqlclient18.
Unpacking libmysqlclient18 (from .../libmysqlclient18_5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdbd-mysql-perl.
Unpacking libdbd-mysql-perl (from .../libdbd-mysql-perl_4.020-1build2_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-core-5.5.
Unpacking mysql-client-core-5.5 (from .../mysql-client-core-5.5_5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-5.5.
Unpacking mysql-client-5.5 (from .../mysql-client-5.5_5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-5.5.
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.5 (from .../mysql-server-core-5.5_5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.5.
(Reading database ... 87306 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql-server-5.5 (from .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhtml-template-perl.
Unpacking libhtml-template-perl (from .../libhtml-template-perl_2.10-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Unpacking mysql-server (from .../mysql-server_5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up libmysqlclient18 (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) ...
Setting up libdbd-mysql-perl (4.020-1build2) ...
Setting up mysql-client-core-5.5 (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) ...
Setting up mysql-client-5.5 (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.5 (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) ...
runlevel:/var/run/utmp: No such file or directory
initctl: Unknown job: mysql
160102 12:58:49 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
160102 12:58:49 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) starting as process 26560 ...
runlevel:/var/run/utmp: No such file or directory
initctl: Unknown job: mysql
Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.10-1) ...
Setting up mysql-server (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
```

I am currently running Ubuntu through crouton on my chromebook. I'm pretty sure that there is enough disk space.

Comment: The reason you're getting the unrecognized service error is that `mysqld` is not the service name on Ubuntu. Try `sudo service mysql start`.

Comment: i tried that and resulted in `start: Unknown job: mysql`
afterwards, I still get the same error when I try to run mysql

Comment: Looks like this could help you out: http://askubuntu.com/questions/296946/upstart-cant-start-mysql